# Oracle performance tuning - iterating table in column section

Tags: oracle, performance, optimization, query-optimization

The below query is taking 220 secs. I want to tune it.
There are mainly three tables used in the query. Two are big and one is considerable smaller.

Counts in the tables:

```
INST        --14851330 records 
INST_S_INC  --52234424 records
INVES         -- 80000 records
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
(
  SELECT CODE
  FROM   CURRENCY CURR
  WHERE  CURR.CURRENCY_ID =
           ( SELECT CURRENCY_ID
             FROM INST  INSTR--14851330 records 
             WHERE INSTR.INVES_ID = INV.INVES_ID
             UNION ALL
             SELECT CURRENCY_ID
             FROM INST_S_INC ISI--52234424 records
             WHERE ISI.INVES_ID = INV.INVES_ID
           )
)
FROM   INVES INV -- 80000 records
WHERE  TRUNC(CREATED_DATETIME) <SYSDATE
ORDER BY CREATED_DATETIME
;--220 secs
```

I tried to rewrite the query as below but it is now taking 418 secs. Any other way to tune it?

```
SELECT
(
  SELECT CODE
  FROM CURRENCY CURR
  WHERE CURR.CURRENCY_ID =ISI.currency_id
  union all
  SELECT CODE
  FROM CURRENCY CURR
  WHERE CURR.CURRENCY_ID =INSTR.currency_id
) code
FROM   INVES INV
       left outer join (
         select INVES_ID,currency_id from INST
       )  INSTR
       on  INSTR.INVES_ID = INV.INVES_ID
       left outer join (
         select INVES_ID,currency_id from INST_S_INC
       )  ISI
       on  ISI.INVES_ID = INV.INVES_ID
WHERE TRUNC(CREATED_DATETIME) <SYSDATE 
ORDER BY CREATED_DATETIME
;--418 secs
```

Comment: What indexes are available? What are the data types for joining columns? What is your execution plan?

Comment: WHERE INSTR.INVES_ID = INV.INVES_ID ---- this is using index
INSTR.INVES_ID - index is created on this

WHERE ISI.INVES_ID = INV.INVES_ID---- this is using index
ISI.INVES_ID - index is created on this

Comment: not able to paste Explain plan due to length restriction but the cost is very low ie 1211.

Explain plan of the first (original) query:

| Id  | Operation                             | Name                       | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                      |                            |  3917 | 70506 |  1211   (3)| 00:00:15 |       |       |

Comment: @swetabhmalaviya Edit your question - do not try to post it as a comment.

Comment: why not fitting here the exec. plan? that row is almost irrelevant without the rest. without the plan were are blind ...

Comment: index is not a magic wand, and does not help in any situation, especially in that case neither, may a full table scan would help much more

Comment: Are you really just selecting `currency.code` and no other columns???

Comment: by the way why is there a select in the select? you need to "remove" it from there

Answer (score 0):

You can change:

```
TRUNC(CREATED_DATETIME) < SYSDATE
```

To:

```
CREATED_DATETIME < TRUNC( SYSDATE ) + INTERVAL '1' DAY
```

Which will allow you to use any index on `CREATED_DATETIME` (rather than having to have a function-based index on `TRUNC(CREATED_DATETIME)`).

It is difficult to interpret your requirements as you have not described what you are trying to achieve or your table structures but you could also try using `EXISTS` and selecting directly from the `CURRENCY` table:

```
SELECT curr.CODE
FROM   CURRENCY CURR
WHERE  EXISTS (
         SELECT CURRENCY_ID
         FROM   INST
                INNER JOIN
                INVES
                ON ( INST.INVES_ID = INVES.INVES_ID )
         WHERE  INSRT.CURRENCY_ID  = CURR.CURRENCY_ID
         AND    CREATED_DATETIME   < TRUNC( SYSDATE ) + INTERVAL '1' DAY
       )
OR     EXISTS (
         SELECT CURRENCY_ID
         FROM   INST_S_INC ISI
                INNER JOIN
                INVES
                ON ( ISI.INVES_ID = INVES.INVES_ID )
         WHERE  ISI.CURRENCY_ID   = CURR.CURRENCY_ID
         AND    CREATED_DATETIME  < TRUNC( SYSDATE ) + INTERVAL '1' DAY
       )
```

Or use a `UNION ALL` within the `EXISTS`.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE  TRUNC(CREATED_DATETIME) <SYSDATE
```

What is the point of this filter? Assuming you don't create records in the future that's basically defining a whole table scan.

Doing performance tuning without an explain plan and details of data volumes, skew, etc is a mug's game but here is my guess:

```
SELECT curr,code
FROM   INVES INV
       left outer join INST
       on  INSTR.INVES_ID = INV.INVES_ID
       left outer join  INST_S_INCISI
       on  ISI.INVES_ID = INV.INVES_ID
left outer join CURRENCY CURR
on CURR.CURRENCY_ID = coalesce (ISI.currency_id, INST.currency_id)
ORDER BY inv.CREATED_DATETIME
;-
```

Comment: What happens when `CURR.CURRENCY_ID = INST.currency_id` but `CURR.CURRENCY_ID  <> ISI.currency_id` and `ISI.currency_id` is not null?